# How to split a React Component by words to apply a different styling to each word?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that renders a page with a title and some content.

The `Page` Component renders the title by applying different styles to all the words (separated by a space) in the title.

It works fine when the title is a string (I can use `title.split(' ')`...), but I need to use a JSX element as the title in some occasion. I'm using React-Intl for the translation, and I'm using a `<FormattedMessage id='...'/>` to translate the title.

How can I split the `FormattedMessage` JSX element into multiple React components so that I can apply an individual style?

Here's a sandbox illustrating the problem:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-flower-0oscs?file=/src/App.js)

Press the "Switch to page..." button to view what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the FormattedMessage component during render isn't possible I think. Also, I had no luck to render it (during render...) to extract the string from the output.

What you could try to do to get a string and then render it like the other titles is to take the `id` from `children.props.id` and resolving it to a string (using the values you pass to `IntlProvider` if those are available at this point.

**Edit:**

Looking at it again, the proper way to do is to apply the formatting inside `FormattedMessage` like so:

```
// App.js line 7
<FormattedMessage id="title.main">
  {txt => <FormattedTitle>{txt}</FormattedTitle>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

This way children will already be formatted and you can use the existing component.